# Are there anyway to use google voice recognizer offline?

Tags: google-api, resources, voice-recognition, pocketsphinx, cortana

I am trying to use `pocketsphinx` but I get about 50% accuracy with it's default `continuous.c` program. But when I try `google voice recognizer`, or `cortana` I get about 100% accuracy! 
It's strange for me that why this happens? Do google or microsoft use better language models? better acoustic models? better dictionaries? or they are better engines than CMU toolkit?

So I am looking for a way to use google or microsoft voice recognizers in offline mode! is it possible? 
Are there googles language model or acoustic model to use with CMU pocketsphinx?

Comment: they use big servers with Big processors on BIG databases for BIGGER recognition chances. Unless you tow a truck wiht those behind you, online's your best guess. Alternatively you need specialized/spezially trained voicerecog tailored to the person - thats how smart phones might get better rates if trained to one person - knowing the persons "quirks" (voicerecog in general)

Comment: Pocketsphinx is your destiny